# TYPO3 8.7.7 include user tsconfig with BackendLayouts option not working

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I have problem when adding BE layout option to select, when insluding file tsconfig, but not when using page TS config field in EditPage->Resources.
I am adding my tsconfig.ts file to page using

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::registerPageTSConfigFile(
    'myextension',
    'Configuration/PageTS/TSConfig.ts',
    'ext tables ts config'
);
```

In **myextension\ext_tables.php** (example is from ext_tables.php but the only difference in name), or **myextension\Configuration\TCA\Overrides\pages.php**.
In **Configuration\UserTS\TSConfig.ts**:

```
options {
    #pageTree.showPageIdWithTitle = 1 <-uncoment and it works!
    pageTree.showNavTitle = 1
}
mod.web_layout.BackendLayouts { # <- this doesn't work!!!!
    113 {
        title = anaele
        config {
            backend_layout {
                colCount = 1
                rowCount = 1
                rows {
                    1 {
                        columns {
                            1 {
                                name = columnname
                                colPos = 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But on the other hand when using page TS config in page edit, I pasted same lines starting from `mod.web_layout.BackendLayouts`and it works just fine and there is new option **anaele** in backend layout selection. I know that my file is included correctly because **options** part works fine.

I emptied **backend_layout** table but got same result.

So what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation gives an example where you can see that path to the script should be **Configuration/PageTS/myPageTSconfigFile.txt** and not **Configuration/UserTS/TSConfig.ts** (file extension doesn't matter). [Link to documentation if someone has the same problem.](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/Field/Index.html#register-static-page-tsconfig-files)